# Trying to find balance in uneven text blocks

Tags: text, page-layout, critique, typesetting, balance

I'm designing a business card for my small business.  The text at the bottom of the card is throwing me off.  I'm separating the employee's name and title from their contact information, to "square off" the bottom corners of the layout.  The employee's name and title comprise 2 lines; the contact information comprises 3 lines.

**Should the two lines go on the bottom left, or on the bottom right, to create the best balance?  If there's really no difference, and either one will work, I'd like to hear that too.**

[image]

Comment: I like the left one better

Comment: Hi CreatedByBrett, I've edited your question to give it a bit more focus. If you think my edits do not reflect your original intent, feel free to [edit] it back. Also feel free to ask more questions, answer other questions and explore everything our site has to offer.

Comment: Thanks @PieBie!  I'm really active on LifeHacks and Movies, but my skills aren't strong enough to answer questions here. ;-) I just drop by occasionally to ask for advice!

Answer (score 4):

Either option is valid.

But, knowing that only 10% of the population is left-handed, I prefer the one that allows to see the person name at the moment of giving the business card.

[image: Business Card]

In spite of being a simple graphic object of reduced dimensions, the text distribution in a traditional way lead to interpreting a reading path.

[image: Reading Path]

Comment: Japanese rules; Take card with both hands, obscuring none of it & study intensely. UK rules; take card, stuff in pocket, hand to secretary later to be digitised & stored with contact details.

Comment: Yes, it's a bit exaggerated, well, the idea is the name on the opposite side of the delivery object. If it were a book, the hand is the spine and the important data on the other side of the page.

Comment: Wow, smart take on this! Thanks! I appreciate the example pics too.

Answer (score 4):

The version on the left is the better one, as a business card is firstly about the person, so name goes first. I would just move the name + title up so it aligns with the phone number on the right. If you don't like how this balances out, consider moving the website to the back of the card on top of some green background or i don't know, play with it :)

Answer (score 1):

Your second example gets away with it better than the first.
Right justified, the phone/email/web looks lumpy with the middle line longer than the others.
Left-justified the eye ignores it.

Answer (score 0):

As always, it depends on what you want to "feature" on your personal, portable, promotional piece. Suppress your ego and poll your target audience.

(Anecdote) My favourite card impressed everyone who saw it and got me awards and interviews for its creativity; but, I never got a commission from it. My most uncreative card is a simple list of my abilities and got me almost all of my most lucrative work. Go figure.

There are four corners and the centre when horizontal and three main areas; top, middle, and bottom when vertical.

Some prefer the trademarked product or service name and mark centred. Some prefer the contact name with title and function under. Some prefer the corporation name and mark. Some want to be seen as non-corporate, non-conformist, creative and unconventional.

Alignment can be used to pull things together, too. Your choices are centred, flush left, flush right, justified (probably forced), and circus (loose).